# If $\phi$ is a $\Sigma_2$ sentence and $H_{\kappa} \models \phi$, then $V \models \phi$?

Tags: logic, set-theory

In the title question, $\kappa$ is any infinite cardinal. It's easy to see that the result is true if $\phi$ is $\Delta_0$ or $\Sigma_1$. I first tried proving the result for $\Pi_1$, but I don't see why if $\forall x \in H_{\kappa} \psi(x)$ is true, $\forall x \psi(x)$ needs to be true (where $\psi$ is $\Delta_0$). I tried doing induction on formula compleity, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it the case that $H_\omega\models\neg Inf$, where $Inf$ denotes the axiom of infinity which is $\Sigma_1$? Do you need other restrictions on $\kappa$ like regularity or uncountability?

Comment: Sorry, I only meant uncountability as $\omega$ is already regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal, then the result is true. The reason is that the Levy reflection theorem says that $H_\kappa\prec_{\Sigma_1} V$, and one can prove this by taking a $\Sigma_1$-elementary Skolem hull of any witness and then collapsing it back into $H_\kappa$. Given the Levy reflection theorem, it implies that $H_\kappa\prec_{\Pi_1} V$, which implies that $\Sigma_2$ truth is upward absolute from $H_\kappa$ to $V$.

You can't generally bring $\Sigma_2$ truth down from $V$ to $H_\kappa$, however; this requires a [$\Sigma_2$-correct](http://cantorsattic.info/Reflecting) cardinal.